# How to move commits in a branch to another new branch in GIT?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have *develop* git branch for my work, I created a new branch called *feature1* and made commit 1,2,3, and 4.

I need to move commit 3,4 from *feature1* branch to a new created branch *feature2*.

The commits 3,4 should be deleted from *feature1* and added to a new branch *feature2*, so the end result should be something like *feature1* with 1, and 2 branches and *feature2* with 3 and 4.

Please note that at the moment I have *develop* and *feature1* branches. *feature2* not added yet.

What is the best way to achieve that? I tried git cherry-pick but wanna make sure the best way to do that.

Comment: Where do you intend to create `branch2`? On which commit?

Comment: I want to create branch2(*feature2*) from *develop* branch and add commit 3,4 from *feature1*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your description correctly, your repo currently looks like this,

```
... -- o [develop]
        \ 
         1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 [feature1]
```

and you want it to look like that

```
         3'-- 4'[feature2]
        /
... -- o [develop]
        \
         1 -- 2 [feature1]
```

Correct? If so, do the following.

First, make sure you're in a clean working state. Then, create and check out a branch called `feature2` that points at the same commit as `develop`:

```
git checkout -b feature2 develop
```

Your repo will look as follows.

```
... -- o [HEAD=feature2,develop]
        \ 
         1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 [feature1]
```

Cherry-pick the two commits of interest (`3` and `4`):

```
git cherry-pick <commit-ID-of-3> <commit-ID-of-4>
```

After that, Your repo will look as follows.

```
         3'-- 4'[HEAD=feature2]
        /
... -- o [develop]
        \ 
         1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 [feature1]
```

Finally, check out your `feature1` branch and reset it two commits back:

```
git checkout feature1
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

Your repo will end up as desired,

```
         3'-- 4'[feature2]
        /
... -- o [develop]
        \
         1 -- 2 [HEAD=feature1]
```

and you'll be in a clean working state.