# Git won't re-merge after resetting a merge without a commit

Tags: git, merge

I started a merge from one branch to another.
Fixed conflicts, did a test run and noticed a problem.

Rather than try to fix the bug post merge, I decided to reset and fix the problem.

Fixed the bug, committed and pushed up the change.

Now when I try to merge again, git tells me I am up to date despite a diff showing many changes I need.

Any idea how I can tell git that I am, in fact, not up to date with the branch I never committed a merge from?

An attempt at a graph for this:

```
develop -\------------\------------------------------\---
         |             \                              \  
         \- Branch ---- \- Canceled Merge-\            \ 
                                           \-- Fixes ---\ Merge that won't see changes
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to represent what happened. Here's a 'full history'

1. Branch from develop
2. Make changes
3. Develop changes happen
4. Start a merge from develop into Branch
5. Cancel merge changes before any commits by using Reset
6. Fix a bunch in Branch, commit changes (and push to remote)
7. Attempt to merge from Develop, git claims up-to-date despite large Diff output.

Comment: Some ASCII graph would help, here.

Comment: I'm not sure what a graph would look like for this, but I'll try!

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023761/how-to-move-commits-in-a-branch-to-another-new-branch-in-git/26024183#26024183) for an example of ASCII graph.

Comment: The part with the canceled merge is what I am unsure how to represent accurately.

Comment: About step 5: what reset command did you run, exactly? `git reset --hard HEAD^` (while on `Branch`)?

Comment: I'm using Source Tree as a crutch, which may be my downfall. The command abbreviated output looks like this: `git [...] reset -q HEAD ...`.  Yes, it was while on `Branch`